# Are there other Identity Matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there only one identity matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&...&...&0\\0&1&0&...&0\\...&0&1&...&0\\...&...&0&1&0\\...&...&...&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ etc..
Or are there different identity matrices for other bases?

A textbook example asks if $[T]_{\beta} = I$ (the $n\times n$ identity matrix) for some basis $\beta$, is $T$ the identity operator?

Comment: Do you know a formula for how matrices change when you change the basis?

Comment: Yes, you arrange the previous matrix as a multiple of whatever amount of each basis matrix, then change the basis and set it equal to the original matrix. The new coefficients will be the changed-basis matrix.

Comment: So far I'm the only person who's up-voted this question.

Comment: Imray, that's a *procedure*; I asked whether you know a *formula*. That is, if you have an operator $T$, and a basis $\alpha$, and another basis $\beta$, do you know a formula relating $[T]_{\alpha}$ and $[T]_{\beta}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we want
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
$$
to be true **regardless of which matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ is,** so that $\begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}$ is an identity matrix.  Since it's true regardless of which matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ is, it must be true in particular if $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, so we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
This last equality clearly implies that $\begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.  Conclusion: if $\begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}$ is an identity matrix, then $\begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.  Therefore there is only one $2\times2$ identity matrix.  And the same argument works for bigger matrices.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, $[Tv]_\beta = [T]_\beta [v]_\beta = [v]_\beta$ for all $v$. Therefore $Tv=v$ for all $v$, i.e. $T$ is the identity on $V$. But to address your real question, here are some more questions for you:

- What happens if I try to perform a "change of basis" on the identity matrix?
- What happens if I try to represent the identity operator (on some $V$) in some basis? What does the identity operator do to the basis vectors?
- What is the definition of the identity matrix, and what should this have to do with bases for vector spaces?

Comment: is $\beta$ the standard ordered basis in your answer, or any basis?

Comment: @Imray: $\beta$ is the basis in your textbook example. But if $T$ is the identity, then $[T]_\beta=I$ for any basis $\beta$.

Comment: You ask, $"What \ happens \  if \  I \ try \  to \ perform \ a \ "change \ of \ basis" \ on \ the \ identity \ matrix?"$  If I change the basis, i.e. from the standard one to something different, the identity matrix changes but the non-zero values are still only on the diagonal though. Is that what you mean? I think I'm getting it then... the identity matrix for a basis is simply a matrix with non-zeroes only on its diagonal and those values depend on the basis...

Comment: @Imray: Here's what I meant. Suppose $B$ is a change of basis matrix (i.e. an invertible matrix). Then the matrix for $I$ under the new basis is given by $B^{-1} I B$. But that is just $I$ again. Can you explain what you mean by the identity matrix "changing"?

Comment: Yes, I mean that if I have a $2 \times 2$ identity matrix, which means it was derived by multiplying 1 to the first and fourth component of the standard ordered $2 \times 2$ basis, and I change the matrices from standard basis to something funnier, the matrix identity changes.